# No notifications for facebook or twitter in Gwibber

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-netbook, display, notification, gwibber

I am using gwibber and have my facebook and twitter account configured in it. My system crashed 2 days ago after an update messed it up and after resurrecting it, I have configured it again. But now it doesnt display any notifications.

I have checked the boxes (in preference) to display All Messages but its still no go.

Need help !

Comment: I updated my Ubuntu, and it solved my problem on reboot :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would delete the /homedir/.config/gwibber directory and then setup the connections again to see if this solves your problem.

Comment: I tried this and it worked initially and then I stopped getting updates. Still looking for a permanent solution, but hope it might work for some folks.